# error: Not in scope: data constructor `Compare'

Tags: haskell

I want to program the card game "Ramsch". i Get the following Error:

```
error:
    Not in scope: data constructor `Compare'
    Perhaps you meant variable `compare' (imported from Prelude)
   |
66 | Compare c1 c2
   | ^^^^^^^
```

```
instance Ord Card where 
Compare c1 c2
      | color c1 == color c2 || rank c1 == Bube && rank c2 /= Bube || rank c1 /= Bube && rank c2 == Bube = compare (rank c1) (rank c2)
      | rank c1 == Bube && rank c2 == Bube = compare (color c1) (color c2)
      | otherwise = GT
```

Why ist "compare" wrong?

Comment: `Compare` (capitalized) must be a type constructor, data constructor, or type class. `compare` (lowercase) is the name of the method defined by the `Ord` class which this instance declaration is supposed to be defining.

Comment: So should i change the name "Compare" ?

Comment: Of course: `compare` is the name of the function you want to define; `Compare` is just as wrong a name as `foobarbaz`. (Even *more* wrong, actually, since `foobarbaz` *could* be the name of a function. `Compare` cannot be a function name.)

Comment: In short, case matters.

Comment: Even if I change the name , the same error keeps coming up. i am confused

Comment: Then you aren't executing the code you think you are. Did you save (and possible reload) the module you are working on?

Comment: it's worth noting that in your code example, even if you change `Compare` to `compare` (which you should as explained above), this won't compile as your indentation is off - the line starting with `compare` needs to be indented. This may not explain the actual problem you're now having but, well, you don't show us the new code and what error it is failing with.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a function, functions start with a **l**owercase, so `compare`:

```
instance Ord Card where 
  compare c1 c2
    | color c1 == color c2 || rank c1 == Bube && rank c2 /= Bube || rank c1 /= Bube && rank c2 == Bube = compare (rank c1) (rank c2)
    | rank c1 == Bube && rank c2 == Bube = compare (color c1) (color c2)
    | otherwise = GT
```

It might however make more sense to implement this as:

```
instance Ord Card where
  compare (Card { rank=Bube, color=c1 }) (Card { rank=Bube, color=c2 }) = compare c1 c2
  compare c1 c2 | color c1 == color c2 = compare (rank c1) (rank c2)
                | otherwise = GT
```

Comment: now it works, thnx

Comment: is this valid? seems like two cards would compare GT both ways, instead of GT one way and LT the other way

Comment: @user253751 Probably not, but the question was about the name, not the algorithm.